# Loading a dataset from my local folder

Tags: python, scikit-learn, python-nolearn

I'm following the example in [this tutorial](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/22/getting-started-deep-learning-python/).

Instead of loading the dataset as follows:

```
dataset = datasets.fetch_mldata("MNIST Original")
```

How can I load my dataset from my "local" folder? Is there a specific structure for the data in order to use it in the example?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is already found in the page you provided

> We make a call to the fetch_mldata function on Line 13 that downloads
>   the original MNIST dataset from the mldata.org repository.
>
> The actual dataset is roughly 55mb so it may take a few seconds to
>   download. However, once the dataset is downloaded it is cached locally
>   on your machine so you will not have to download it again

It'll load the dataset once, then use the locally cached copy.

Source: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/22/getting-started-deep-learning-python/

EDIT: There's some information on http://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/mldata.html, e.g.

> The MNIST database contains a total of 70000 examples of handwritten
>   digits of size 28x28 pixels, labeled from 0 to 9

and

> After the first download, the dataset is cached locally in the path
>   specified by the data_home keyword argument, which defaults to
>   ~/scikit_learn_data/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I meant to say my "own" dataset, and not the MNIST. Is that more clear? Thanks

Comment: Then use the data_home keyword argument.